# 日本語に違和感：バッジ「子鹿」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

バッジ "yearling" の訳語が「[子鹿](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling)」となっています。

「1年間アクティブなメンバー」に与えるバッジであることを考えると、おかしな日本語になっています。

**UPDATED:** バッジ名について包括的に議論する「[バッジ名の日本語訳](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1505/)」が出来ましたので、そちらに統合したいと思います。

Answer (score 9, accepted):

「年輪」なんてどうでしょう。（たまたま、yearling の year-ling にかかってる。。)

Comment: 個人的には好きですね。なんか面白い気がします。

Comment: イイネ！ 毎年積み重なるニュアンスを良く言い表せる気がします。

Answer (score 1):

確かに、英語のニュアンスは伝えれないです。ダジャレっぽい名前ですが、子年はどうでしょうか？【ねずみどし】ではなく、【ことし】と読めば、1年間という意味に関係があるニュアンスわかりますか？

Comment: バッジの一覧をいつか全部見直すべきと思いますね。子年は伝えているといいですし、全然違う方向（日本語でもっといい提案）があれば、それも是非！

Comment: 「周年」ではあまりに堅苦しいかなぁと考えていたので、「子年」とはナイスな妙訳ですね(笑) ただ、そもそも"Yearling"＝「子鹿」となるニュアンスを理解していないため外しているかもしれませんが、無理に「子」という漢字をいれると余計混乱する人がいるとも感じました。（小説"The Yearling"／邦題「[子鹿物語](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AD%90%E9%B9%BF%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)」から来ているのでしょうか）

Comment: @yohjp 英語で「Yearling」の意味は「[1歳〜2歳の動物、特に子牛、子羊か子馬](https://www.google.co.jp/?#q=define+yearling)」です。本のタイトルなどではなく、通常の英語の言葉です。動物に例えているけど、悪い意味より、小さな動物が可愛いとおもっているのかな？

Comment: 名詞(noun)だと本当に「子鹿などの1～2歳の動物」の意味だったんですね。形容詞(adjective)なら「1つ歳を取る」ですね。勉強になりました。

Answer (score 1):

堅苦しい訳しか思いつきませんでしたが、候補を挙げておきます。どれも今一つ…

- 周年
- 一周年
- 当歳

日本語の「一周年」は"(1st) anniversary"を想起させるのと、このバッジが1年おきに何回も獲得できることを考慮すると、ちょっと微妙かもしれません。

Comment: 実は何回ももらえます（毎年）：http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=22656